# In the book C Programming Language Counting characters

Tags: c

So when I count characters, I don't get any output. 
What is the output of this code? Because when I compiled it and executed it, all I get it blank black space.
I thought it was supposed to COUNT. I don't get it. Please excuse me, I just started learning C. 
All I want to know is what the heck does this code supposed to show as the output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 1st version */

main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
         ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving to the program ?

Comment: I found a solution, and any letters for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm going to walk you through what this code does line by line, and maybe that'll help.

Pull in some definitions, specifically the one for `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Declare the `main` function:

```
main()
{
```

Declare and set a variable for the number of characters:

```
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
```

**Here's the key** -- loop, getting character after character, until the character received matches `EOF`, which is Ctrl-D on most systems.

```
    while (getchar() != EOF)
```

Increment the `nc` variable (increase it by 1) for each character.

```
         ++nc;
```

Print the number of characters as a long integer.

```
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program, it will wait for user input (collected via `getchar()`).

You must type some characters first into your terminal and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to send the *end of transmission* character (what `EOF` will end up matching).

Comment: What do you mean by type some characters first?

Comment: On the output or in the code? Plus I tried ctrl + d right now but still doesn't work! :( What is the problem in this?

Comment: @user101750 You said you compiled and executed it. You program should be running, waiting for user input. So, type some characters. When you're done, press ctrl+d to send the EOF symbol.

Comment: Control+D doesn't do anything for me... All it shows is this.. ^D

Comment: @user101750 Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I figured it out.. I just replace EOF with '\n' so I can get the number as soon as I type characters. It works that way for me.

Comment: @user101750 If you're using Windows, try ctrl+c or ctrl+z. I don't have Windows available to test.

Answer (score 0):

Every file ends with `EOF` .So the program counts the number of characters until `EOF` is reached . Iteration is done using `while` loop .

You should provide input to the program .

Make a text file sample.txt in the current folder where the program resides , then give the text file as input to the program

```
program < sample.txt
```